# Error when starting redmine on Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger, redmine

I've a Ubuntu server with redmine installed. I don't know the details because another guy installed everything and he doesn't work with us anymore.

We performed a reboot of the server for maintenance, and after this redmine does not start anymore. When I point to that address of the server I obtain a NGINX error page on my browser:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.

Technical details for the administrator of this website
Error ID:
dbda8097
Details:
Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server.

Please read the Passenger log file (search for the Error ID) to find the details of the error.

You can also get a detailed report to appear directly on this page, but for security reasons it is only provided if Phusion Passenger is run with environment set to development and/or with the friendly error pages option set to on.

For more information about configuring environment and friendly error pages, see:

Nginx integration mode
Apache integration mode
Standalone mode
```

So I go to `/opt/nginx/logs/error.log` for checking the error, and I obtain the following fragment associated to that ID.

```
App 1388 output:     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/passenger-6.0.4/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[ E 2020-06-23 13:47:54.8167 1104/Tm age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/data/redmine: The application encountered the following error: Child already added (RuntimeError)
  Error ID: dbda8097
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-Gfstmf.html

[ E 2020-06-23 13:47:54.8234 1104/T9 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-3] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is dbda8097. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

The file `/tmp/passenger-error-Gfstmf.html` does not exists so I can't check its content.

I don't know what error means.

This is the configuration file `nginx.conf`

```
#user  nobody;

worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/passenger-6.0.4;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

root /var/data/redmine/public;
passenger_enabled on;
client_max_body_size 10m;

}

}
```

This file is not modified before the reboot.

Where should I start to check? I've seen that all folders referenced in this file exists, and I don't think that's a redmine problem, rather a ngix one because it's in its log, not redmine one.

What should I do in order to debug and solve this problem?